# C++ custom array slice class with const correctness

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, slice

I'm trying to make a custom array slice class that can handle arbitrary, possibly negative strides and am wondering how to do it with const correctness:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

template< typename T >
class ArrayView
{
public:

    ArrayView( void* pointer, int strideInBytes, int length )
    {
        m_pPointer = reinterpret_cast< unsigned char* >( pointer );
        m_strideInBytes = strideInBytes;
        m_length = length;
    }

    const T& operator [] ( int index ) const
    {
        const unsigned char* p = m_pPointer + index * m_strideInBytes;
        return *( reinterpret_cast< const T* >( p ) );
    }

    T& operator [] ( int index )
    {
        unsigned char* p = m_pPointer + index * m_strideInBytes;
        return *( reinterpret_cast< T* >( p ) );
    }

    int length() const
    {
        return m_length;
    }

private:

    unsigned char* m_pPointer;
    int m_strideInBytes;
    int m_length;

};

void printFromReadOnlyView( const ArrayView< int >& view )
{
    for( int i = 0 ; i < view.length(); ++i )
    {
        printf( "%d: %d\n", i, view[i] );
    }
}

void useRef( std::vector< int >& ref )
{
    // works fine
    ArrayView< int > view( ref.data(), sizeof( int ), ref.size() );
    printFromReadOnlyView( view );
}

void useConstRef( const std::vector< int >& constRef )
{
    // const error
    ArrayView< int > view( constRef.data(), sizeof( int ), constRef.size() );
    printFromReadOnlyView( view );
}

int main()
{
    std::vector< int > v( 10 );
    for( int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i )
    {
        v[i] = i;
    }

    useRef( v );
    useConstRef( v );
}
```

The function useConstRef() results in a compile time error since constRef.data() is a const pointer and ArrayView's constructor takes in a non-const pointer.

Essentially, I want ArrayView to be either const (read-only) or non-const (read-write).

I can try adding a constructor that takes in a const pointer instead, but then I'd have to store the const pointer and remember which version I am. Can I get away with using only a single class, or do I have to make separate ReadWriteArrayView and ReadOnlyArrayView versions?

Comment: `ArrayView< int >` and `ArrayView< int const >` should be two different types...

Comment: +1 to K, and I'm pretty sure you're going to find out that const data() pointer and your constructed *non*-const void pointer aren't gonna jive.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: have you looked at `std::valarray`, `std::slice`, etc?

Comment: I have but I actually need something a bit more flexible. I'm planning on doing some fun non-aligned iterations through multidimensional arrays.